# Use BaseAdapter for Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-spinner

The mission is to fill the spinner with values from a POJO object. Before doing that, I was checking with normal String values and BaseAdapter.

I have an activity in an activity group.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_date_filter);

    startMonth = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.startMonth);

    startMonth.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(getParent(), new ArrayList<String>()));
}
```

And the layout_spinner_row.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinnerValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my adapter class is:

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter{ 

private List<String> alertList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, Object results) {
    alertList = (List<String>) results;
    //just check if it works. 
   //in real, actual object fits in
   alertList.add("January");
    alertList.add("Feburary");
    alertList.add("March");
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return alertList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return alertList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_spinner_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.spinnerValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerValue);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.spinnerValue.setText(alertList.get(position));
    return convertView;
}




static class ViewHolder {
    TextView spinnerValue; //spinner name
}
}
```

And when I click on the spinner, I get the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1686): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@4135fa38 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

I could not find any valid answer for the issue. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what you need to do with it explain clearly

Comment: @TheMechanic check edits please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your view to corresponding view objects, in order to get the spinner working.
To do you will need to change the oncreate of your activity:

```
View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.activity_date_filter, null); 
this.setContentView(viewToLoad);
```

For complete explanation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: I tried the aforementioned code before. But, somehow it did not work then! Thanks anyway. But I am still confused the way spinner works. it works now. When I set contentView in my activity, why it does not set view for spinner as well?

Comment: Thats because you embed a second xml as spinner view to your activity. Even you can set multiple layouts to yous spinner (like dropdownview) ect, therefore you inflate the spinner views as well as the activity

Answer (score 1):

From your adapter code, i can say **you haven't initialized `LayoutInflater`** and without doing it you are trying to inflate layout. So inside your constructor, use:

```
 this.mInflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: I inflate layout from the context. See adapter constructor. mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);